# How to disable test mode while keeping warning for unsigned drivers (Windows 10)

Tags: drivers, windows-10, digital-signature

I looked online but what I found are only ways to disable driver signature verification on Windows 8, 10 to be able to use unsigned drivers. This is not what I need.

In my case (Windows 10 64 bit) I installed unsigned drivers (Extra Magic for Apple Touchpad) and I got the "test mode" text on the lower right. The boot/reboot/shutdown background was always red.

Now I removed the drivers and I also used Autoruns ([How to find drivers breaking digital signature enforcement in Windows 7 64bit](https://superuser.com/questions/930861/how-to-find-drivers-breaking-digital-signature-enforcement-in-windows-7-64bit)) to verify that the drivers are actually removed. In fact, something was left and loaded from System32/Drivers and it appeared yellow.

Now that in Autoruns I see no more drivers for the Touchpad (but still something else red, like the driver for the X-Rite i1 Display Pro, the screen calibrator), the boot/reboot/shudown background color is always green. This makes me think Windows too knows that no problematic drivers are present.

Now I would like to keep the check for driver signature on, as it was before, but I would also like to get Windows back in the standard mode I was used to, without "Test mode, Windows 10 build 10240" and the fixed green boot/reboot/shutdown background (before all this, the color was variable).

Comment: Have you enabled driver signature verification at this point?

Comment: I never disabled or enabled it, I only agreed once to install the unsigned driver. I did that by clicking on "install anyway" or similar in a dialog by Windows itself.

Comment: Based on the answer to this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/695090/can-i-install-unsigned-windows-drivers-to-work-without-test-mode-or-disabling-dr?rq=1) test mode would only be enabled if you disabled the requirement to have signed drivers.  So go ahead and make sure signed drivers are actually turned on.  You can reverse the process in this [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/509971/using-unsigned-drivers-in-windows-8?rq=1) to do that.

Comment: Better post it as full answer... seems to be complete.

Comment: I would but I have been dealing with users downvoting every answer I submit out of spite.  I also don't believe the answer I would submit is worthy of being submitted.  All I have done is post links to existing answers, if you feel you can answer the question yourself, you should do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem after uninstalling Extra Magic.

**To Disable Test Mode**

- Open Command Prompt (as an administrator)
- Run `bcdedit /set testsigning off`
- Restart your PC

**Note**

If you disable test mode while you have drivers installed that need test mode (unsigned drivers), those drivers will stop functioning.

**Source**

http://maxedtech.com/about-testmode/